# How to clone private AWS codecommit repo to on-prem server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

We have an AWS account with No NAT or Internet Gateway and a private codecommit repository. We have our VPC direct connection to the on-prem vpc and we have opened port 443 from the on-prem firewall towards the AWS VPC. The on-prem server doesn't have internet connectivity. We have created interface endpoints to access codecommit in the VPC. The on-prem server has an AWS profile with an access key and secret key. Now we would like to clone, update and push the repo to the on-prem server.

**Update**: since we have configured the AWS profile on the on-prem server. We are trying the git HTTPS URL option to clone the repo. But looks like it is trying to hit the public endpoint of the codecommit service. Therefore it just keeps on trying to get any response from the service and fails in the end. like below

```
git clone https://git-codecommit.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/xxx-xxx-projects
Cloning into 'xxx-xxx-projects'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/xxx-xxx-projects/': Failed to connect to git-codecommit.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

Comment: What's the error when you are trying to clone it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't set up the routing correctly yet.

First, check if you can access the VPC interface endpoint from within the AWS VPC. An easy way doing that is launching an EC2 instance in that VPC and running the [Reachability Analyzer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html) with the instance as source and interface endpoint as target.

If you can't reach the endpoint, verify that you have followed the [procedure in the CodeCommit docs for setting up the endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/codecommit-and-interface-VPC.html) correctly. To double check, you can also run `nslookup` from the EC2 instance in the AWS VPC. This verifies that the IP address correctly resolves to that of the ENI of the VPC interface endpoint. As target for the lookup, use the public DNS address of CodeCommit's Git endpoint (replace region):

```
nslookup git-codecommit.<YOUR REGION HERE>.amazonaws.com
```

If this works now, you should check the routing to the public DNS name of CodeCommit from your on-prem network. For the AWS VPC, AWS created a hidden private hosted zone in Route 53 behind the scenes when the interface endpoint was set up, which takes care of routing DNS requests to the public endpoint to the private endpoint of the CodeCommit interface endpoint. This is why the nslookup earlier returns the private IP address of the endpoint rather than the public IP address.

If `nslookup` doesn't return the same IP address (that of the ENI of the interface endpoint) when you run the command on-prem, you'll have to set up your DNS resolver to route requests to that domain to the AWS VPC-provided DNS (example on how to do this using "Unbound" [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-dns-resolution-between-on-premises-networks-and-aws-by-using-unbound/)).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Daniel. We will check this

Comment: Hi Daniel ... we checked and nslookup is able to fetch the private IP of the codecommit endpoint. But the problem is git command looks for the public codecommit URL and there is no option to specify endpoint address in the command like we can so in AWS s3 command. Due to which git codecommit is not working on prem.

Comment: Do you run nslookup agains the public CodeCommit address? That is the one that must return the IP of the ENI of the interface endpoint. If that's not the case, then the DNS set up isn't working properly yet.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a relatively old post. However in an attempt to do the exact same thing I ended up here and in case anyone else is trying to do the same...

If you have network connectivity from your on-prem system to the interface endpoint, you need to use the 'vpce' specific dns name from your git-codecommit endpoint to access the repo.

to clone:

```
git clone https://vpce-<vpc id>-<more id>.git-codecommit.<region>.vpce.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<name of repo here>
```

Credential helper configuration is relevant, and also confirm you are not trying to go through a proxy.